# Haskell: initialise a list with symbols?

Tags: haskell

In Haskell, is there a way of initialising a list and declaring symbols in that list at the same time?

Currently I do this:

```
import Data.List
main = do
  let lambda = "\x03BB"
      xi = "\x926"
      bol = "\x1D539"
      cohomology_algebra = [ lambda, bol, xi]
  putStrLn $ xi
  putStrLn $ show cohomology_algebra
```

However I have a long list of symbols and I worry that i forget to put them all in the list (it has happened)

Ideally I would do something like:

```
main = do
  let cohomology_algebra = [ lambda = "\x03BB", bol = "\x1D539", xi= "\x926"] -- does not compile
  putStrLn $ show cohomology_algebra
```

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Use a [`Data.Map`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.2.1/docs/Data-Map-Strict.html) to store your symbols where names as key and charcode as value. Then `elems` function should give you the `cohomology_algebra` list.

Answer (score 1):

Not a perfect solution, but you could use

```
let cohomology_algebra@[lambda, bol, xi] = ["\x03BB", "\x926", "\x1D539"]
```

This will trigger a  *runtime* error if the two lists above have different length (at the point where the names are demanded).

It's not optimal, since this check should be at compile time instead. Further, in this code style we have to separate the identifier form its value too much, making it possible to swap some definitions by mistake.